# Importing a binary file into NASM

Tags: linux, nasm

I have a binary file `codes.bin` that I want to 'include' in my NASM assembly program's .data segment.

I know I can hexdump the binary and add it as initialized data in the usual way by copying and pasting, but I was hoping there was a better way

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ah, I was looking for the `incbin` pseudo-instruction. [I should have RTM](http://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.11.02/html/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.2.3)

Here is a sample code:

```
incbin 'file.bin'
```

Answer (score 1):

For do that you can use this syntax:

```
incbin "codes.bin"
```